# Code in R, and Normally Distrubuted

Tags: r, data, data-analysis

```
library(MASS)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x = MPG.highway, data = Cars93, facets = ~Origin, geom = "histogram", fill = Origin, binwidth = 2)
```

I have this preceding code, and I had a question about the dataset. The question is does it look normally distributed I feel like saying that USA is normally distributed; meanwhile, the Non-USA bin is not normally distributed? I apologize in advance this is a data analytics question, which I was going to ask in Math StackExchange but it had R code.

[image: DataSets]

Comment: Please post the plots.

Comment: @Dave How? Do I? I am programming in R-Studio

Comment: Found it! Yay I did it

Comment: @Dave I saved it 300x300 and it still looks weird.

Comment: Imho there's not enough data points to conclude anything, but a [Shapiro test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) `shapiro.test(Cars93[Cars93$Origin=='USA','MPG.highway'])` gives a p-value of 0.055, which I would interpret as borderline.

Comment: @Erwan It's ok I was using statistics tests like Wilcox, and t-test, and I was looking for advice about its normality.